# Finding the number of documents that contain a term in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, information-retrieval

I have an Elasticsearch index that contains around 2.5 billion documents with around 18 million different terms in an analyzed field. Is it possible to quickly get a count of the number of documents that contain a term without searching the index?

It seems like ES would store that information while analyzing the field, or perhaps be able to count the length of an inverted index. If there is a way to search for multiple terms and get the document frequency for each of the terms, that would be even better. I want to do this thousands of times on a regular basis, and I can't tell if there is an efficient way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html) to just return the count from a query, instead of a full document listing.

As far as whether Elasticsearch gives you a way to do this without a query: I'm reasonably confident Elasticsearch doesn't have a store of that information outside the index, because that is exactly what a lucene index *already does*. That's what an inverted index is, a map of documents indexed by term. Lucene is designed around making looking up documents by term efficient.